# PDO stmt->execute results in MySQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Could anyone help me figure out why the following code returns a MySQL syntax error?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `message`(`id`, `message`, 
        `scramble_level`, `scramble_key`) 
        VALUES (:id, :message, :scramble_level, :scramble_key');


$stmt->execute(array(':id' => 'NOW()', ':message' => $theMessage, 
        ':scramble_level' => $scrambleLevel, 
        ':scramble_key' => $scrambleKey));
```

This results in:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mising your closing bracket `)` around your `VALUES()`

```
VALUES (:id, :message, :scramble_level, :scramble_key)');
```

Comment: very foolish of me, thanks.